# SASS with normalize and Codekit

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, codekit

When I'm trying to compile my project that include only 
@import "normalize" from [compass-normalize gem](https://github.com/ksmandersen/compass-normalize) it tells me
thie error

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:     
LoadError on line 161 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/bin/../lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: no such file to load -- compass-normalize
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

okey. So I have reinstalled all gems but it still doesn't work. What is  more when I'm doing `compass watch` in command-line it works! And actually it compiles... what's wrong with codekit than?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?  http://incident57.com/codekit/help.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have that specific gem? If not, you could try:

```
sudo gem install compass-normalize
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Why is it best to not use sudo? Won't you be asked for an admin password anyhow?

Comment: nope. most of ruby gems do not make system wide changes. chances are that if a system wide change is needed, that will be from a new library about the gem (eg: libxml) which will be added as sudo and then the gem can be added from a simple user. BTW `compass-normalize` does not use sudo in their documentation. https://github.com/ksmandersen/compass-normalize