# "no such file to load" 960gs gem (a.k.a.) ninesixty

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to use the 960 grid system in my compass project.

So I installed the gem with:

```
gem install compass-960-plugin
```

Then in my compass project I add the folowing rule to my "**config.rb**" file:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'ninesixty'
```

But when I try to import in my **screen.scss** with:

```
@import 960/grid
```

It's not working. The error I get is as follows:

Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:

> Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:
>
> LoadError on line 161 of /Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/compass/bin/../lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:
>   no such file to load -- ninesixty Run with --trace to see the full
>   backtrace

Comment: Does it work if you run Compass via command line?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333888/sass-with-normalize-and-codekit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem isn't in your LOAD_PATH. Did you `require 'rubygems'` before requiring the 960 gem? Are you using something like Bundler?

Comment: Not using Bundler (yet). I'm new to this compass thing, and wanted to use a grid. I use Codekit which natively has Susy installed so that also works for me.:) Thnks anyway..